# Robot Class - Unhandled exception type AWTException

Tags: java, compiler-errors, awt, awtrobot

So, I was was tinkering around with the Robot Class in Java. I am a very new Java Programmer, but I have deeper roots in other languages. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot bot = new Robot();
        bot.mouseMove(50, 50);  
    }
}
```

All I was trying to do was see if I can control the mouse, as in, moving it to 50, 50. However, in Eclipse it puts a red X next to

```
Robot bot = new Robot();
```

..saying..

```
Unhandled exception type AWTException
```

And won't let me run it. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#Robot%28%29) declares that it throws the checked exception (and another unchecked exception). Either surround it with a `try/catch` or declare the main `throws` it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to try/catch exceptions:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(50, 50);  
    }
    catch (AWTException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

or throw the exception:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Main throws AWTException{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(50, 50);  
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.*;

public class remote{

     public static void main(String[] args) {


         try
            {
            Robot bot = new Robot();
            bot.mouseMove(50, 50);
            trace("działam");
            }
            catch (AWTException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

     public static void trace(String s){
         System.out.print(s.toString());
     }

}
```

It's work for me not before i added bot.mouseMove(50, 50) to TRY instruction.